# Blender Rotation

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have an object in blender that I am trying to rotate by importing values from a csv file. The values are in rows 4-6 of the csv file and they are in degrees so I want to use euler rotation. However, even though the object is set to euler rotation and when I add the property to the object through the script it is using euler rotation when I view the resulting animation it shows the wrong value. For instance if 39 degrees x is put in it shows 2236 degrees because it thinks it is getting radians. How can I make it know that it is receiving euler values?

```
    rotation = [float(x) for x in row[4:7]]
    ob.rotation_euler = rotation
    ob.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler", frame=frame+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct it expects radians. Simply `import math` and convert your degrees to radians through [`math.radians()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians).

```
rotation = [math.radians(float(x)) for x in row[4:7]]
ob.rotation_euler = rotation
ob.keyframe_insert("rotation_euler", frame=frame+1)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help. Do you know why it still expects radians when it is explicitly told to use Euler rotation (twice at that)?

Comment: That's because Euler rotation doesn't specify that the input is in angles. It's a specific way to perform the rotation, just like using Quaternions or the Rodrigues Formula.

Comment: When working with trigonometric functions in computer science or mathematics you will mostly use radians instead of angles. In this case Blender's API expects radians, which isn't unusual.